# Jquery row selecting in a button onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table (id of the table is county_table) with plenty of lines like this:

```
<tr>
<td><input class="text" type=text name=param1 maxlength=2 size=2></td>
<td><select class="text" name=param2><option value=1>Live<option value=2>Test</select></td>
<td><input class="text" type=text name=param3 ></td>
<td><input class="text" type=text name=param4 ></td>
<td><input class="text" type=text name=param5 ></td>
<td><input class="text" type=text name=param6 ></td>
<td colspan=2><input class="button" type=submit value=New onclick="function_new($('#county_table  tr:eq(1)'))"></td>
</tr>
```

The onclick function would manage the table data, and maybe send an AJAX, so I need to get the all elements of the table.

The bad thing with that solution is that if I insert a new row the whole table row selection would be messed up, so I'd like to change the `tr:eq(1)`, something like `this.tr` or something like that, is the button know his ancestor and get the given object?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `$(this).parent().parent()` for a better performance. 
http://jsperf.com/parentparentvsclosest/2

But if you are looking for code simplicity, then you could go for `$(this).closest('tr')`.

Comment: thank you! i really don't know which one is the better cause every answer is perfect, appreciate your work guys! need to give to first one the accept mark

Answer (score 2):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the parent tr of the button being clicked.

```
var trOfButton = $(this).closest('tr');
```

> Description of closest: For each element in the set, get the first
>   element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and
>   traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate very much your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 - $(this).closest('tr');
```

OR

```
 - $(this).parent().parent();
```

.closest() will give you closest tr to the button and .parent() will return parent element(td) and again it's parent will return that row

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate very much your answer!